# how to make inputbox pop up in the second monitor if my mouse pointer is there?

Tags: autohotkey

How do you detect which monitor my mouse pointer is on?

I am using multiple monitors, and I am trying to make an inputBox pop up in the center of the monitor where my mouse is

Right now I have the following code:

```
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
MouseGetPos, X_m, Y_m
InputBox, UserInput, Title, Prompt,, 300,150,X_m, Y_m
```

This pops up the inputbox exactly where the mouse pointer is, but I want it to be on the CENTER of the monitor(where mouse is).

Comment: Where does it pop-up instead?

Comment: where my mouse is, not the center. I want it to be on the center of the area of the monitor where mouse occupies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check [SysGet](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SysGet.htm).

Using the subcommand `Monitor [, N] of SysGet`, and `MouseGetPos` you can deduce which monitor the mouse is located and set the msgbox accordingly